# mockito @Mock does not inject into named @Resource as expected

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mockito

I have a class with three named @Resource members as follows:

```
@Resource(name = "contactsPaginationRequestValidator")
private PaginationRequestValidator paginationRequestValidator;

@Resource(name = "integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator")
private PaginationRequestValidator integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator;

@Resource(name = "contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator")
private PaginationRequestValidator contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator;
```

After upgrading to Mockito 1.9.5 from 1.8.5, the test began failing. The test suite mocked PaginationRequestValidator only once as follows:

```
@Mock
private PaginationRequestValidator mockPaginationRequestValidator;
```

This resulted in only the third of the three instances being injected as the following sysout makes clear:

```
paginationRequestValidator (contactsPaginationRequestValidator) is null
integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator (integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator) is null
contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator (contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator) is mockPaginationRequestValidator
```

Obviously, there was a change in behavior between the two versions. I am assuming the older version injected the mock into all three of fields - which would still be an acceptable solution to me.

Being the smart guy that I am, I figured I could get the test to pass by providing the name associated with the resource, as follows:

```
@Mock(name = "contactsPaginationRequestValidator")
private PaginationRequestValidator mockPaginationRequestValidator;
```

This resulted in similar, but subtly different results. The third field, not the expected targeted field was mocked, as above, but the it was mocked with the name provided in the @Mock. See the sysout:

```
paginationRequestValidator (contactsPaginationRequestValidator) is null
integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator (integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator) is null
contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator (contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator) is contactsPaginationRequestValidator
```

This is totally unexpected behavior. Yet, there is more. When I then added a similar mock for the second field, all the fields ended being mocked as expected:

```
@Mock(name = "contactsPaginationRequestValidator")
private PaginationRequestValidator mockPaginationRequestValidator;

@Mock(name = "integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator")
private PaginationRequestValidator mockIntegerMaxPaginationRequestValidator;
```

Sysout:

```
paginationRequestValidator (contactsPaginationRequestValidator) is contactsPaginationRequestValidator
integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator (integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator) is integerMaxPaginationRequestValidator
contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator (contactsSearchResultPaginationRequestValidator) is null
```

While this is exactly as I would expect, it seems completely contradictory to the previous tries.

I have the documentation that explains this behavior, but it does not suggest a way to inject the same mock into all three. Is this possible, or must I create multiple mocks and then change individual test cases to use the "correct" mock?

The test suite uses the @InjectMocks annotation.

Comment: You just have to inject all three of them manually.  Mockito only looks at the type of each field, not its name; so if you have multiple fields of the same type, there's no way to control which mock gets assigned to which field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation of `InjectMocks`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) says:

> Field injection; mocks will first be resolved by type, then, if there is several property of the same type, by the match of the field name and the mock name.

So you need 3 mocks, each having the name of the field to inject with the mock.

Comment: I believe that's an error in the documentation.  Maybe @Brice or Szczepan could confirm this.

Comment: I think I remember having used this feature successfully.

Comment: That I understand, though interestingly the documentation and the actual usage do not seem in-sync. But, that was not my question. My question specifically was asking if it was possible to inject the same mock into all fields of the same type as seemed to be happening in 1.8.5 (all of our tests worked then, so seems a logical assumption).

Comment: @JBNizet I suspect that the behaviour changed between 1.8.5 and 1.9.0, and the documentation didn't keep up.  I'm not certain.

Comment: @BillTurner No, it isn't since 1.9.0. The behavior in 1.8.5 was a bug. Which pretty much explains why the javadoc didn't change ;)